What to do with a child who is seeking attention negatively and now is becoming agressive towards others?
I'm not a parent but I work in the early education field. We have a child who is very strong willed and is now seeking attention in a negative way. We are at a loss as to what to do and how to handle the situation. These outbursts could be over the smallest thing and turn into a tantrum causing them to hit people, throw and break things.

is he seeking attention, or to get something he wants?  Does he throw tantrums if ignored?  if he got what he wanted but was immediately ignored again would that end his tantrums (not that I recommend doing that)?  You're current description is rather sparse, It would be easier to give more useful advice with a little more details on the kids mindset, what causes tantrums, if he is having trouble with emotional regulation or just being stubborn, why you think it's explicitly attention seeking behavior etc?

As I said in my comment more detail would make it easier to answer this question, since There are many things that can lead to a child having tantrums and not all of them should be addressed in the same way.  Still, I've volunteered with a lot of kids so I've seen a bit of everything, which means I've had to deal with lots of situations that might apply here and can go into detail about each one individually.
Attention-seeking behavior
I had a very similar situation in a Sunday School setting.  In my case the child in question would run out of the classroom and as far away as he could get because he knew I would have to chase him and he thought that was funny.  He would also talk over lessons without seeming to even understand why that was a problem.  Though with my 'problem child' I don't think he was a bad child or trying to cause trouble.  He mostly didn't understand the difference between negative and positive attention or why his actions were so disruptive to the classroom.
In this case my solution was to show him that it was better to seek positive attention then negative attention.  I did this by increasing the level of attention he got when he was being good while removing attention when he was engaged in attention-seeking behavior.
For running away this meant that I simply didn't chase him.  I let him run all the way down the church hallway and all I did was ask him to come back to the room before going inside myself.  I kept an eye on him of course to make sure he didn't do anything that may put him in danger, but I pretended to have ignored him.  When he didn't get what he wanted - to be chased - he came back to the room on his own.  A few repeats of this and he stopped trying to run away because it just lead to him ending up alone instead of getting attention.
When he tried other ways of getting attention he would get time out, and I had to stay next to him for those or he would get up and leave it.  However, I made it clear to him that I would not engage him even if I was staying next to him.  I never said anything to him other then the occasional reminder that we couldn't talk in time out.  I didn't engage him or look at him.  Even when he tried to run away I'd stop him and set him in his chair without otherwise interacting with him.  It was very important he did not get the attention he wanted during a time out so he didn't see misbehaving as an effective way to get attention.
Along with this I gave him more attention when he behaved well.  During lessons he was allowed to sit on my lap (when the lap wasn't otherwise needed to handle another child - he was pretty okay with sharing or being kicked off when I had to handle other kids so long as he got to stay close).  I'd complement him when I saw him behaving as soon as I could.  It made him happy to get this special attention and compliments and so he started behaving in the way that got it!
The net result was that his mother ended up telling us that she had been planning to wait another year before entering him into elementary school but since she had seen him make so much progress in our classroom she felt comfortable with his starting school earlier.
Boundary-testing tantrums
Most tantrums are kids testing boundaries.  They hope to get what they want by fighting you and seeing if you cave.  For these standard sort of tantrums the solution is to simply not cave.  Tell the kid they will not get what they want the way they are behaving.  For the most part you just need to wait the kid out at that point.  If you stay consistent and never give in to a tantrum, eventually the kid will learn it won't work and will stop trying.
To help a child figure this out faster I try to do two things.  First I reiterate that I can't do things they want when they are screaming over and over.  I make it clear that the rules are that screaming means you lose privileges.  If I have reason to think that tantrums work for the kid elsewhere, like at their home, I will go further by adding a caveat that when they are here with me we can't handle screaming, to help them put together that the rules might simply be different with me then at home.
I also try to give the kid alternatives that demonstrate how things can work if they behave, but only if they stop screaming.  To demonstrate that it's possible to negotiate and find compromises if not crying.
Of course once a kid starts a tantrum they often forget why they are crying and end up crying just for the sake of crying after a while.  For that I also make liberal use of distractions.  Let them cry a bit, long enough to forget why they are fighting, then bring out some sort of distraction to draw them out of their crying.
So let's use my 3 year old niece who I visited last weekend as an example.  She had 3 tantrums while I was there.  The first was when I told her we couldn't go into the room I used to take them to play since their parents had converted it to a reading room.  I explained the rules and that we wouldn't be allowed in the room while she was walking me to it - this ensured she heard the reason why before she started crying.  When she realized we locked the door I let her cry a bit then picked her up and suggested we play one of her favorite games with her brother which worked as a good distraction to stop her crying.
Later she cried because she wanted a particular triangular magnetic tile which her brother had first.  Her brother tried to give it to her to stop the crying but I didn't let him at first - they last thing you want is for a kid to get what they want by having a tantrum!  I explained instead that she couldn't get the tile while screaming.  After a little while I told her it would have been her turn except that she had to wait longer to get it because she was screaming.  I told her if she stopped screaming she could have it immediately since it was her turn, but if she kept screaming she would have to wait longer to have it.  She impressed me by trying to reign in her crying - I had honestly expected her to ignore the offer and have to wait.  So after she managed to get herself down to mild sobbing instead of screaming I complimented her and let her have the piece.
The third time she was just tired.  Recognizing she wasn't testing boundaries and just exhausted I offered her a compromise for the thing she wanted that I wouldn't have offered her if I thought she was testing me, then took her to her room for her nap time.  Which is an example of the third explanation for tantrums...
Lacking emotional regulation
Sometimes crying is not (just) testing boundaries but part of a larger issue with emotional regulation, such as you get when a toddler is tired and easily driven to crying.  Escalating from mere tantrum to hitting and breaking things may be a sign that there is a larger emotional regulation issue beyond mere boundary testing.
My goddaughter has intermittent explosive disorder so I'm very familiar with this situation.  She's usually great and well behaved, and then she will have an issue where she gets stubborn and upset, and she will escalate, up to hitting and breaking things.  However it's not entirely a choice: she literally struggles with emotional regulation and doesn't know how to de-escalate once she get's worked up.
Much of the solution is still the same: don't let them get what they want by screaming, don't reward them with constant attention, reiterate the rules and that they won't get what they want with their current behavior, and wait them out.  However it may be coupled with helping them to regulate their emotions.  For instance we recommend my goddaughter take some time alone when she gets too worked up and we've praised her for going to her room and falling asleep while screaming because at least she didn't escalate or make things worse; for her that was a step in the right direction.  We also teach her how to recognize her own emotions, when she is getting worked up, and how to stop herself before she gets worked up into a full meltdown.
Of course I doubt this kid has Intermittent Explosive Disorder, but there are many ways that young children may struggle with emotional regulation.  The point is to figure out what upsets them, help provide coping mechanisms to help them to regulate, and teach them to use them, all while still making sure they don't get rewarded for their tantrum by getting something they want.
For example having a 'cool down' spot where upset kids can go when too worked up can be quite useful.  This is not a timeout, it should not be presented as a punishment or a place they are being forced to go because they are bad.  It is a place with soft (not breakable!) things away from the commotion of other kids where a child can calm themselves without having to deal with other stressers.  This should be presented as a place they should want to go to help themselves feel better, not a punishment, and as such they should be praised for allowing themselves to be placed there and staying there until they feel better.
I can't give more advice here without knowing the kid, what upsets them and what, if any, difficulties they may have with emotional regulation since there is such a wide variance between kids unfortunately; how you help them really needs to be targeted to the child and what proves to work best for them.
Though there is one source to go to for help with that.
Involve the parents!
If the child is escalating to hitting and breaking things the behavior is likely severe enough to bring up with the parents.  Ask them what their rules are for such behavior in their home and what has worked for them.  Do they know why the kid is so frustrated, or what best calms them?  They know the child better then you, they may already have figured a lot of this stuff out.
If the parents have a good policy for how to handle tantrums you could try using the same system when the kid is with you.  Having the rule consistent between home and your care will help the kid to figure them out faster.  Of course not all parents will have a good solution; I've had more then one parent whose solution was give in to the tantrum which is the worst solution.  But you can at least hear the parents out and what has seemed to work for them and try to use that to see if it provides you with insight on the best approaches for handling the child.
Communicate with the child
For all of these solutions one key thing I've already mentioned many times is communication.  Tell the kid what the rules are.  Explain to them why they can't do something, but also offer alternatives and things they can do (unless they're already screaming: negotiation for other alternatives are usually cut off if they're already screaming so they don't think it's a reward for screaming).  In fact communicate with them and tell them when they lost the right to negotiate because they are screaming!
Since kids don't listen as well when screaming reiterate things before and after tantrums, explain to them why the tantrum wasn't working after they have calmed down.  For instance when I told my niece she would have to wait to get the piece she wanted if she kept crying I fully expected her not to hear me.  My intent was to remind her of that fact after she had gotten the piece and had stopped crying, to make sure she realized that not only did the tantrum not get it for her sooner but that she actually waited longer as a result.  I didn't expect her to register that during the tantrum.
The more you communicate the rules, reasons for them, and what does and doesn't work the sooner the kid will understand and accept them.
Figure out what upsets them and what alternatives they like
Sometimes you can pre-empt tantrums by understanding what the kid wants and offering them alternatives that will still appease them.  Other times you may be able to recognize something likely to upset a child and simple avoid that situation in the first place.
If you can figure out what things upset the child the most you can then help to communicate that.  If you know their problem is that they are usually tired and it's making them cranky you can help them to recognize the feeling and that a nap will help.  If they are hungry you can help them see eating will help.  In short, if you know what's upsetting them you can then better teach them what to do to fix that problem and feel better.

+1 Wish I had parenting advice this clear, 8 years ago.

This might be the longest stack exchange answer I've ever read completely - and I don't even have kids.

@DonQuiKong Sorry.  I hyperfocus and am fundamentally incapable of writing short answers ;)

Wow! This is a very comprehensive answer on the subject.

I think how you handle these issues is pretty situational, because it depends on the whys for the most part.
The one red flag I see in your question though is the words "strong willed".  That makes me think that there's a pretty good chance the child is working on developing their independence, and running into walls (figuratively or not!).  Children in the preschool age range are learning that they're capable of doing a wide range of things, and don't yet understand why they might not do those things.
How are you handling it when they want to do something that is not permitted, or want to not do something that is required?  Where possible, if you're able to work with the child to understand the thing they must or must not do, and perhaps have a slightly more nuanced answer than 'no' or 'yes', it will help children immensely in developing that understanding of their limits.  The child may simply be frustrated, just like you or I might be when running into something we don't understand - think about how some people react to the seemingly arbitrary rules at places like TSA checkpoints, for example.
Beyond that, consider whether these outbursts are coming from a consistent trigger. Are they always based on hitting a limit? Consider whether "the smallest thing" to you is actually small to a preschooler. Is it possible they're having issues controlling their emotions due to something external?  Not enough sleep, not enough food?  Talk to the parents, see if there is anything going on at home - changes like a new baby or new pet or parent working late or who knows what can make it harder to regulate emotions (for adults also!).
When the child has an outburst, how are you working with them?  Do you work with them to understand their emotional reaction?  Removing them from the situation can be necessary sometimes to protect themselves or others physically, but it's not always helpful for growth - learning how to process the emotions in the moment is a skill too, so when you're able to work with them without removing them from the situation it's a good idea.
